# Amazon Cognito: Mobile to web cross login with QR Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-cognito, qr-code, nest

**Hi there**
I want to implement cross login with QR Code.
For Auth provider, I use Amazon Cognito.
So I signin in my mobile app, scan QR code in my Web app, and after that I should signin in Web App. Main part is already implemented, but as I see, default auth method of Amplify: Auth.signIn doesn't support login with token or so.
Any solution for that? Thanks.

I'm expecting to initiate signIn process with Amplify method or with Lambda trigger.
From mobile app I recieve access token and trigger signin event with Pusher service

Comment: [Custom authorisation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html) is probably the way forward.